# Component dispose consistency

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, controls

I have a class that inherits System.ComponentModel.Component. The component spawns a bacground thread that makes a long blocking call that waits for outside event. In my Dispose the thread is signaled to finish its call and return. Can I be sure that app will always call my Dispose? How can I ensure that my thread does not linger and prevent client app from terminating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I ensure that my thread does not linger and prevent client app from terminating?

Make the thread a [background thread via `Thread.IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx).  This will keep the thread from keeping the process alive.

Comment: Note that this doesn't 'trigger' the Dispose method.

Comment: @Emo No - it just keeps the thread from preventing the app from terminating.  A used Component is typically disposed by its container, though - but I wanted to address this as it seemed to be the root of the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to guarantee that `IDisposable.Dispose` will be called on your object. You can expect finalizer to be called in all normal cases.

As Dispose is only convention, not requirement you have to enforce it through good coding practice and potentially run time checks in finalizer (if you want).

The good way of not blocking the app is not to make long synchronous calls. Most APIs have asynchronous versions that are much easier to cancel/ignore completion part. If you can't - use  Thread.IsBackground as Reed Copsey suggested.